# Memtest86 is freezing at 60%

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I'm using Memtest86 5.01 at my ThinkPad x230 and tried to test my ram today.I have 3x4Gb. When testing Memtest is always freezing at "Test 60%". I'm not even able to close the program with ESC, so I have to turn off my laptop entirely.
Then I tested with only 4GB (with both modules in both slots each) and then the test is running without freezing. I also did not see any errors.
What can be the problem and does it mean there is something wrong with my memory or mashine?

Comment: What OS is installed?

Comment: The additional memory has failed.

Comment: @Moab Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @John But when I test the memory separately it's not freezing

Comment: Is the memory all the same brand and same speed?

Comment: @John yes its exactly the same. Both are SK hynix 4GB PC3 - 12800S

Comment: Try a different memory test utility.

Comment: @Moab the build in memory test programm of windows didn't found any issues

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Sounds like memtest program is freezing, not a problem with memory itself.

Comment: @Moab I had some stuttering from time to time while working on my laptop. I was suspecting it's maybe caused by the memory and feel confirmed after Memtest86 freezed. But after the Windows 10 test didn't found any problem I decided to reinstall my system completly and currently on Ubuntu 20.10 the problem seem to be gone. Thank you for helping